# php grabs link from html option value to Post into Email

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a online e form system, where a user has the option to send a form link to a colleague. The form contains a dropdown of all the forms on the page which contain a link. They then go on to enter the to and from fields.

Email sends but i cant seem to grab the link from the option value.

Form:

```
<select name="forms" autofocus style="width:54%">
<option> Select a form</option>
<option value="Form1">
<a href="Form1.html">Form1</a></option>
<option value="Form2">
<a href="Form2.html">Form2</a></option>
</select>
```

(I have not included the whole form just the part i cant get the links for)

How can i use PHP to post the link?

Thanks for any help you can give.

I am not trying to redirect the user. I want to be able to grab a link (Via PHP) depending on what the user selects.

Phil

Comment: You just receive the value php side. Then depending on that value, you decide what to do/to send in your php script.

Comment: You cannot have links inside `option` tags. If you want to send the link with the form then you need to set it on the `option`'s `value` attribute: `<option value="Form1.html">`. The value that is sent with the form is the value in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just set the value of the option to be the URL rather than putting the link in the text part of it?

```
<select name="forms" autofocus style="width:54%">
<option> Select a form</option>
<option value="Form1.html">
Form1</option>
<option value="Form2.html">
Form2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: there's actually no need to send the url from server to client in "value" attribute just to get it back from client to server when form gets posted, better get the simple info of which form is asked for, and react consequently serverside. This also avoids escaping/encoding issues for more complex urls (with text parameters for instance)...

Comment: Indeed, but who knows of peoples reasons for doing things ;)

Comment: This works best for me. will have to figure out how to hide the link behind some text now. But Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<select name="forms" autofocus style="width:54%" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option> Select a form</option>
<option value="Form1">
<a href="Form1.html">Form1</a></option>
<option value="Form2">
<a href="Form2.html">Form2</a></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to redirect the user. They are selecting the link to send to a colleague. I need to use php to send the email. Within that email the php needs to copy the link within a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this php side:

```
if $_POST['forms']=='Form1' {$link="full/url/for/Form1.html";}
if $_POST['forms']=='Form2' {$link="full/url/for/Form2.html";}
//send your email here with the value of $link
```

Besides, you don't need any `<a href...>` in your html.

```
<select name="forms" autofocus style="width:54%" method="post">
    <option> Select a form</option>
    <option value="Form1">Form1</option>
    <option value="Form2">Form2</option>
</select>
```

(or check for `$_GET['forms']` instead of `$_POST`depending of the chosen `method` in your html form).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

Include this Javascript to get URL on the currentf form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
currentUrl=window.location.href ;
</script>
```

Recieve it in PHP

```
<?php
echo "currentUrl: ".$_GET['currentUrl']."<br>";
?>
```

Alternatively, just get current url in php

```
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```